# Crude Monte Carlo Integration Variance

Tags: variance, monte-carlo

Suppose we want to evaluate the integral:

$$I = \int_a^b f(x)dx\ $$

where f(x) is a smooth function defined on the interval [a, b]. In the "crude"-MC method, the integral is approximated as

$$I = \int_a^b f(x)dx\ \approx\ \frac{b-a}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N f(x_i) $$
where $x_i$’s are uniformly distributed random numbers between a and b, and N is the number of samples.
My **question** is why the *variance in f* is given by the equation below:
$$\sigma^2 = \frac{b-a}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N f^2(x_i)- [\frac{b-a}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N f(x_i)]^2 $$
when the variance equation is $Var(X) = E[X^2] - E[X]^2$. In other words, how can we just plug in $I$ into the variance equation without taking into account of its expected value?

Moreover, how can we further prove the actual *error in the integration* is given by:
$$\sigma_I = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt {N}}$$
I think my main confusion arises from I'm not sure for which variable we are calculating the variance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When considering the approximation
$$\int_a^b f(x)\,\text dx\ \approx\ \frac{b-a}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N f(x_i)=\hat I$$
the lhs is an average of iid random variables, the $(b-a) f(X_i)$'s, with variance
$$\text{var}\, \hat I = \dfrac{1}{N} \text{var}\, \{(b-a) f(X_i)\}=\dfrac{(b-a)^2}{N} \text{var}\, f(X_i)$$
This variance can thus be approximated by a convergent estimator
$$\dfrac{(b-a)^2}{N} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^n \{f(X_i)-\overline{f(X)}\}^2
=\dfrac{(b-a)^2}{N^2} \sum_{i=1}^n f(X_i)^2 - \left[\frac{(b-a)}{N} \sum_{i=1}^n f(X_i)\right]^2$$